# What is the difference between object and .Object in OOP in R?

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I'm studying S4 classes and methods and I got confused to know when to use .Object and object (using as an argument to functions on classes). I don't understand if is there any difference between them.

For example, Would be correct:

```
setGeneric("getTimes",function(object){standardGeneric ("getTimes")})
setMethod("getTimes","Trajectories",
          function(object){
            return(object@times)
            }
          )
```

or:

```
setGeneric("getTimes",function(.Object){standardGeneric ("getTimes")})
setMethod("getTimes","Trajectories",
          function(.Object){
            return(.Object@times)
            }
          )
```

Comment: I think you're a bit confused here. Generics can have any (number of) arguments you like. Were you thinking of *validity* methods, which have to be a function of a single argument `object` (see `setValidity`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should [avoid the curly braces](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s4.html#s4-generics) around `{standardGeneric("getTimes")}`.
The short answer for your question: there is **no difference** between the 2 code in your example. You were defining `getTimes` as a brand new generic function of your own. You can specify its arguments name whatever you like (`object`, `x`, `xobject`, `.Object`). Then, when you write the methods for the generic function, your methods' arguments name **must match** with the generic function's arguments name. For example:

```
setGeneric("getTimes", function(object) standardGeneric("getTimes"))
setMethod("getTimes", "Trajectories", function(object) object@times)
```

If not follow, there will be error (technically, a warning because R automatically/"silently" correct it. However, in my opinion, R should stop and throw an error in this case):

```
setGeneric("getTimes", function(object) standardGeneric("getTimes"))
setMethod("getTimes", "Trajectories", function(x) x@times)
# mismatch between `x` argument name in method and `object` argument name in generic
```

In the case you want to define methods for **existing generic**, you should use function `method.skeleton`.
Example 1:

```
setGeneric("getTimes", function(xobject) standardGeneric("getTimes")) # generic function is defined
getTimes # type function name without parentheses to get a summary of the generic
method.skeleton("getTimes", "Trajectories", stdout())
# copy this method skeleton to your script/source file and modify to your need
```

Example 2, `show` is a predefined generic with `object` as argument (see `?show`) or you can type `show` without parentheses to check. Therefore, `setMethod("show", "Trajectories", function(.Object) .Object)` will be error. You can proceed using [this approach](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s4.html#show-method), however, I think `method.skeleton` is a pretty useful alternative:

```
> method.skeleton("show", "Trajectories", stdout())
setMethod("show",
    signature(object = "Trajectories"),
    function (object) 
    {
        stop("need a definition for the method here")
    }
)
```

Example 3, `initialize` is a generic function and its argument `.Object` may be defined (type `initialize` without parentheses to check). From my understanding, the reason `.Object` is chosen as argument name in this case to invoke the feeling of a prototype object (you can read more at `?initialize`). Similarly to Example 2, use the `method.skeleton` helper function:

```
> method.skeleton("initialize", "Trajectories", stdout())
setMethod("initialize",
    signature(.Object = "Trajectories"),
    function (.Object, ...) 
    {
        stop("need a definition for the method here")
    }
)
```

**Note**: there is a special case for replacement/assignment function (`<-`), that is its last argument must be named `value`. [Read more](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#replacement-functions). For example:

```
setClass("Trajectories", slots = c(times = "numeric"))

setGeneric("getTimes", function(x) standardGeneric("getTimes"))
setMethod("getTimes","Trajectories", function(x) x@times)

setGeneric("getTimes<-", function(xobject, value) standardGeneric("getTimes<-"))
setMethod("getTimes<-", c("Trajectories", "ANY"), function(xobject, value) {
    xobject@times <- value
    xobject
})

# test drive
m <- new("Trajectories", times = 32)
getTimes(m)
getTimes(m) <- 42
getTimes(m)
```

R will not output any error or warning if you use other name (`new_value` in below) when defining the generic and accompanying methods. However, when you use it, R will error:

```
setGeneric("getTimes<-", function(xobject, new_value) standardGeneric("getTimes<-"))
setMethod("getTimes<-", c("Trajectories", "ANY"), function(xobject, new_value) {
    xobject@times <- new_value
    xobject
})

# test drive
m <- new("Trajectories", times = 32)
getTimes(m)
getTimes(m) <- 42 # error because the right side of <- is always considered as `value` argument
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't sure if using "object" has a special meaning or if any word can do the job. But I understood perfectly!